# Form data in html file is not linking to .js file

Tags: javascript, html

Goal:

1. Create front end using html to read data stored in a firebase database
2. Display data within date range provided by user
   So far I have created an html file with a form to gather user input (start and end date). The file is being hosted using tomcat server.

How can I link my .js to my .html file and retrieve the user input?

When I run this code I see the for and I'm able to input data. It seems the submit button is not linked.

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <form id="userForm">
    <h1> Baby Detection In Car </h1>
        Please enter information below.<br/><br/>
        Start Time (mm/dd/yyyy): <input type="text" name="start" id="start"><br>
        End Time (mm/dd/yyyy): <input type="text" name="end" id="end"><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form> 
        <script src=index.js></script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js file

```
//Event listener for user input to form 
document.getElementById('userForm').addEventListener('Submit',submitForm); 
function submitForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 //Get values 
    var start = getInputVal('start');
    var end = getInputVal('end');
}
//Function to get user input 
function getInputVal(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value; 
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with [java]? What's the java angle to this question?

Comment: This was a mistake. I am new and mistook java for java-script.

Comment: try putting quotes around your src name <script src="index.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Upon further inspection, the .js file is linked correctly. 
There was no call to show user the data once submit was pressed.